# SQL statement to show only previous month data

Tags: sql, oracle

When I run my query, it pulls all the data. I only need to pull data for the previous month. Maybe there is a code that read the ACTFINISH date from jun 1st to 30th.

Please let me know what the code to pull previous month data is and where I need to input that.

```
SELECT WORKORDER.WONUM,
  WORKORDER.STATUS,
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.REPORTDATE,'DD-MON-YY') AS "REPORTDATE",
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.ACTSTART,'DD-MON-YY') AS "ACTSTART",
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.ACTFINISH,'DD-MON-YY') AS "ACTFINISH",
  WORKORDER.HASCHILDREN,
  WORKORDER.ACTLABCOST,
  WORKORDER.ACTMATCOST,
  WORKORDER.ACTTOOLCOST,
  WORKORDER.WORKTYPE,
  WORKORDER.DESCRIPTION,
  WORKORDER.ACTSERVCOST,
  WORKORDER.EXT_DISTWORKTYPE,
  WORKORDER.LOCATION,
  MAXPRD.LOCATIONS.EXT_OFFICE,
  MAXPRD.LOCATIONS.EXT_STATECODE,
  WORKORDER.OWNERGROUP,
  CASE MAXPRD.LOCATIONS.EXT_SRV_POLYGON
    WHEN 'BOF'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'CDA'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'COL'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'DAV'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'GOS'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'KEL'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'KLF'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'LAG'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'LEC'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'MED'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'PUM'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'RIT'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'ROS'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'SAN'
    THEN 'GAS'
    WHEN 'SPO'
    THEN 'GAS'
    ELSE 'ELECTRIC'
  END AS TYPE,
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.SCHEDSTART,'DD-MON-YY') AS SCHEDSTART,
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.SCHEDFINISH,'DD-MON-YY') AS SCHEDFINISH,
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.TARGCOMPDATE,'DD-MON-YY') AS TARGCOMPDATE,
  TO_CHAR(WORKORDER.TARGSTARTDATE,'DD-MON-YY') AS TARGSTARTDATE
FROM WORKORDER
INNER JOIN MAXPRD.LOCATIONS
ON WORKORDER.LOCATION   = MAXPRD.LOCATIONS.LOCATION
WHERE WORKORDER.STATUS IN ('COMP', 'CLOSE')
AND WORKORDER.SITEID    = 'OPS'
```

Comment: Your code looks more like Oracle than MySQL, so I fixed the tags.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you just want

```
and trunc(ACTFINISH,'MM') = trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1),'MM')
```

If there is an index on `actfinish` that you want to use

```
and actfinish >= trunc(add_months(sysdate,-1),'MM')
and actfinish <  trunc(sysdate,'MM')
```

Answer (score -1):

Just add a condition to your where clause.  You should be able to use something like this

```
AND ACTFINISH BETWEEN '01-JUN-2015' AND '30-JUN-2015'
```

Comment: Be sure to mark my answer as the answer.  You can also build the dates based off of SYSDATE.